# Variable won't increment

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to make a password manager with python and sqlite. I'm setting a variable to 0 and incrementing it by 1 every time the user enters the wrong password, once the variable `x` is equal to 3 the program should shutdown but the variable `x` only increments 1 time before staying as 1. How do I fix this?

```
master = 'pass'


def main():
    inp = input("\nPassword\n>>> ")
    global x
    x = 0
    if inp == master:
        print("Welcome Back!\n")
        print("1. View Database\n2. Edit Database\n")
        task = input(">>> ")
        if task == 0:
            pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        if x == 3:
            print("You have failed to enter the correct password 3 times")
            os.exit()
        else:
            x += 1
            print(x)
            main()
main()
```

Comment: You set `x` to zero at the start of each run of `main`. So even if it has just been incremented, it is reset again. You would be better off writing an explicit loop and getting rid of the recursion.

Comment: Rather than having `main()` call itself recursively like that (and making `x` a global variable), I suggest that you instead have a loop inside it that will only allow the maximum number of attempts to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this is to put `x = 0` outside `def main():` part.
If you do this, the incrementation should be good for all code.

```
x = 0
def main():
    global x
    [rest of code]
```

Otherwise you set x = 0 every time inside `main()` loop.